# Asus Xtion Pro Live poor framerate

Tags: kinect, openni, xtion, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am excitedly trying out our newly arrived Xtion Pro Live cameras.  Unfortunately, I see behavior that on the same laptop, Kinect runs at 30FPS (as determined by rostopic hz), while through the same USB port the Xtion gets < 10 FPS, and sometimes drops to "no new messages" briefly.  I'm on 11.04, using electric, and see this using both the openni-dev and ps-engine that "come with" electric and the newer versions available at pointclouds.org.  I have tried restarting the driver many times.  Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12277/asus-xtion-pro-live-poor-framerate/) by [Peter Henry](https://answers.ros.org/users/1510/peter-henry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not having this issue but I did download and compile the latest OpenNI and PrimeSense Sensor sources, stable branches : http://www.openni.org/Downloads.aspx (you need to git clone them).

You'll have to install OpenNI (first) and the Sensor (second) packages on top of your openni-dev Debian package (effectively overwriting the files of the Debian package). You can do this by following the build and installation instructions in the README files in the top directories of both packages.

If it doesn't work, you can revert all by calling the ./install.sh script with the -u option for both packages and then to do

```
sudo aptitude reinstall openni-dev
```

So it's quite safe to try this out.

---

Originally posted by [psoetens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1336/psoetens/) with karma: 76 on 2012-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1